# Can't get op-amp to work

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I'm working on a project where I want to amplify a small voltage from a DC motor to around 1-2 V using an LM358. I'm using a battery to supply Vcc and I don't need it to be able to output negative voltages.

I've used this schematic to try and make a non-inverting amplifier but I can't seem to get it working on my breadboard.  Any insights into what I'm doing wrong? (In this case I have it powering an LED just as a placeholder.)

[image: schematic]

Comment: Not working means what? Post voltages with the pot at 50%. Show an image of your actual breadboard,

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell why do you think it does not work. How do you expect the circuit to behave, and how does it behave, and is the behaviour observed in simulation or in real life?

Comment: For future reference, please draw all positive voltages pointing upwards and negative/ground pointing down.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit needs pin numbers and decoupling capacitors, but at a high level it should work as intended over a small part of the R1 adjustment range.

> I can't seem to get it working

tells us nothing.  In what way is it not working?  What is the voltage on pin x?  Is it pure DC, or does it have an AC component?  With useful information, you will get better answers.